# Match a recurring number pattern in data stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, pattern-matching

I have an ongoing stream of data that consists of nothing but a single integer for every piece of data I receive.

So I get something like:

```
6462
6533
6536
6530
6462
376135
623437
616665
616362
616334
```

Here a graph of a complete pattern.
[image]

Now I know I will get a specific pattern in this stream of ints with a certain error margin, I know it will never be the exact same pattern but I will get a very similar one every now and then. Its a very high amplitude pattern similar to the numbers shown in the example. It basically oscillates between 3 states and shows a finer grained difference in every state but the interesting parts are the big differences.

I have no experience in pattern matching and analyzing data streams and no idea where to start. Ideally I would provide my code an data set and it would check if the incoming data stream is matching that data set by a certain margin.
Which is my biggest problem, I can't compare complete data sets, I have to compare a complete set with one that is being constantly generated and see if my pattern is starting to occur in this constant stream.

The main program is currently running in JavaScript/node.js and I'm not sure if JavaScript is suitable for this task but it would be great if I can stay in JavaScript.

Though if there are libraries that help with these kind of tasks in other languages I would be keen to test them out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for the purposes of your application of pattern matching you need to determine the existence of the pattern before it has finished expressing. Is that correct?